# Scope of a function in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

Suppose I have to define a function called `foo`.  Suppose that, in order to define it, I use some auxiliary functions `foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3`, ...

When I load the file containing those functions, from the top-level I can use all of them.  Instead I want to "see" from the top-level only the function `foo` and "hide" the others.  How can I achieve this result?

Comment: I'm a few years rusty on this one, but check out `flet` -- it's like let for functions.

Comment: And if there is also another function `goo` which uses `foo1`,  `foo2`, `foo3`, ...?  I can't make `foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3`, ... local to `foo`, because this way `goo` won't see them

Comment: You could also do something with the Common Lisp package system, but be careful--the package system has some subtleties that I have trouble wrapping my head around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`flet`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_flet_.htm).

E.g.,

```
(flet ((foo1 (...) ...)
       (foo2 (...) ...)
       (foo3 (...) ...))
  (defun foo (...) 
    (foo1 (foo2 (foo3 ...))))
  (defun goo (...)
    (foo2 (foo1 (foo3 ...)))))
```

Comment: Additional note: if the functions defined by one `flet` would need to reference each other, use `labels` instead.